# JQuery AJAX JSON.Not able to fetch the result from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am having a JSON file as mentioned below :-

```
{   head: {
    link: [],
    vars: [
      "CompanyName",
      "Company_Name",
      "Foundation_URI",
      "Foundation_Name",
      "Latitude",
      "Longitude"
    ]   },   results: {
    distinct: false,
    ordered: true,
    bindings: [
      {
        CompanyName: {
          type: "uri",
          value: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_Christian_Broadcasters"
        },
        Company_Name: {
          type: "literal",
          xml:lang: "en",
          value: "United Christian Broadcasters"
        },
        Foundation_URI: {
          type: "uri",
          value: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christchurch"
        },
        Foundation_Name: {
          type: "literal",
          xml:lang: "en",
          value: "Christchurch"
        },
        Latitude: {
          type: "typed-literal",
          datatype: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          value: "-43.52999877929688"
        },
        Longitude: {
          type: "typed-literal",
          datatype: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          value: "172.6202850341797"
        }
      },
      {
        CompanyName: {
          type: "uri",
          value: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_Christian_Broadcasters"
        },
        Company_Name: {
          type: "literal",
          xml:lang: "en",
          value: "UCB Media"
        },
        Foundation_URI: {
          type: "uri",
          value: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christchurch"
        },
        Foundation_Name: {
          type: "literal",
          xml:lang: "en",
          value: "Christchurch"
        },
        Latitude: {
          type: "typed-literal",
          datatype: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          value: "-43.52999877929688"
        },
        Longitude: {
          type: "typed-literal",
          datatype: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          value: "172.6202850341797"
        }
      },
      {
        CompanyName: {
          type: "uri",
          value: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kathmandu_%28company%29"
        },
        Company_Name: {
          type: "literal",
          xml:lang: "en",
          value: "Kathmandu"
        },
        Foundation_URI: {
          type: "uri",
          value: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christchurch"
        },
        Foundation_Name: {
          type: "literal",
          xml:lang: "en",
          value: "Christchurch"
        },
        Latitude: {
          type: "typed-literal",
          datatype: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          value: "-43.52999877929688"
        },
        Longitude: {
          type: "typed-literal",
          datatype: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          value: "172.6202850341797"
        }
      }
    ]   } }
```

The problem that I face is I am using `$.getJSON()` which is available in JQuery and am not able to retrieve relevant information from the JSON file. The code I use is as follows :-

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
       $.each(data.results.bindings,function(i,res)
               {
                    $('#jsonData').text(res.CompanyName.value);

                }
               );
     });
```

I dont even get an error :( . I am using eclipse for Dynamic web projects and using tomcat server for deploying my application. The JSON file is a local file in the WEB-INF directory itself and the `$.getJSON()` call is able to easily fetch it. The only problem is that I am not able to retrieve the data ??

When I replace the `$.getJSON()` by the code below i get an error stating `error:[object Object]`

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "data.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){alert("SUCCESS");},
      error: function(e){alert("error:"+e);}
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

$.getJSON() will fail silently if the JSON Data is not formatted correctly. Your JSON data is missing double-quotes around the key values.

Use the following format checker to correct your errors:
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's AJAX methods mostly fail silently - lucky for you I know what the problem is.

Your JSON is invalid - all keys in JSON MUST have double quotes around them.

See here for more details / an easy way to check:
http://jsonlint.com/

EDIT:
Just occurred to me that if you're using Tomcat, you could use the excellent java net.sf.json library to translate arrays, lists, lists of beans etc to json directly without hand coding anything. You can find it here: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Make a note that the following portion is invalid:

```
xml:lang: "en",
```

either

```
xml:{lang: "en"},
```

or

```
xml:"", lang: "en",
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, jQuery JSON commands are working with JSON strings where each key has to be quoted. So try `{"head" : ...}` instead of `{head : ...}`

Comment: too many capable people around :-) but the answer still holds